# Possible Bug with Amazon DynamoDB for Unity using ScanAsync

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

While trying to scan my new database based on a boolean ScanCondition I encountered what I think is a bug.  I have the following:

```
try{
  var search = context.ScanAsync<Card>(new ScanCondition("Contest",ScanOperator.Equal,false));
  search.GetRemainingAsync(result=>{
    if(result.Exception != null){
      //Handle Exception
    }else{
      foreach(Card a in result.Result){
      print("RESULT: " + a.Name);
    }
  }
 });
}
```

The database has a card, TestCard, with a value of Contest = false.  However, this ScanAsync does not return the TestCard.  If I change the ScanOperator to ScanOperator.NotEqual and again scan for cards with Contest = false, it will return the card erroneously.  Apparently, it is not translating between the DynamoDB Boolean and the C# bool values.

Has anyone else encountered this bug?  I was under the impression that all primitives translated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Scan" feature of a DynamoDB table will only compare strings, binaries, and numbers.  Scanning on a different primitive type doesn't throw an error, but it also does not compare correctly.